# Placing some controls above and some below plot

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The code below is something I wrote quickly to simulate the problem I'm having with more complex code. I use Row (or Grid) to get the first 2 manipulate variables (a and b) on one line above the plot and I want the other 2 variables (c and d) in one line below the plot. 
I can get the controls where I want them without Row (or Grid) but then they appear in a column. Whenever I add Row all controls appear to have the same placement. 
I wasn't able to find any other posts that could help me with this problem.

```
Manipulate[
 f = a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d;
 Plot[f, {x, -4, 4}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 3, ControlPlacement -> Top}],
   Control[{{b, 2, "b"}, 0, 5, ControlPlacement -> Top}]
   }],
 Row[{
   Control[{{c, 1, "c"}, 0, 4, ControlPlacement -> Bottom}],
   Control[{{d, 0, "d"}, 0, 2, ControlPlacement -> Bottom}]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You can get more flexibility in positioning if you use a `DynamicModule` and build up the grid and control elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is how you might do it within the framework of Manipulate:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d, {x, -4, 4}], 
 Row[{Control[{{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 3}], Spacer[20], Control[{{b, 2, "b"}, 0, 5}]}], 
 Row[{Control[{{c, 1, "c"}, 0, 4}], Spacer[20], Control[{{d, 0, "d"}, 0, 2}]}],
 ControlPlacement -> {Top, Top, Bottom, Bottom}
              ]
```

It looks as follows:[image]
Have fun.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how I didn't even think of this.

Comment: This code is like a little miracle.

Comment: However, there is something strange in the result! Here, controls a and b are at the bottom, whereas controls c and d are at the top! And after some trial and error I have found that `ControlPlacement -> {Top, Bottom}` works, where it seems that `Top` points to the first row and `Bottom` to the second.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrating the advice of rm-rf:

```
DynamicModule[
 {f, a, b, c, d},
 f = a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d;
 Column[
  {Row[{"a  ", Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 3}], "b  ", 
     Slider[Dynamic[b], {0, 3}]}, Frame -> True],
   Dynamic@
    Plot[f, {x, -4, 4}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {-50, 50}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Row[{Style["f(x)=", 20], Style[TraditionalForm[f], 20]}]],
   Row[{"c  " Slider[Dynamic[c], {0, 3}], "d  ", 
     Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 3}]}, Frame -> True]}, Frame -> True
  , Background -> LightYellow]]
```

I am sorry for not using some parameter ranges, but aim was illustrative:

[image]